# How can I resist the vaccine better?

Tags: pandemic-2

This seem impossible to me wherever I start, because Madagascar always seem to survive.

Only once have I infected all countries, but the vaccine finished me off before I could win.

How can I make a virus that doesn't succumb to the vaccine so quickly?

Comment: I have modified your question to highlight the main problem you were having. General tips don't work very well for Arqade. I haven't played this, though, so I don't even know if its possible, so feel free to re-word it.

Comment: but isn't this a discussion forum?

Comment: Nope. Please take our about tour to understand what we do.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make your virus resist vaccines, research the "Drug" resistance under the disease tab, as shown below.

[image: Drug resist location]

The higher the drug resistance level, the more likely your disease is to beat the vaccine.

Source: Personal experience and [this guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Beat-Pandemic-2/)